# How to create multiple CheckBox programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, checkbox, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in `UIViewController`. In that `UITextView`, need to insert Multiple CheckBoxes for notes.

How to create multiple checkBoxes??

```
I have created Multiple CheckBoxes for `UIButton` Click, But When I Select or DeSelect operation, all ChecKBoxes Value changes.
```

How can I create multiple checkBoxes and create method for those CheckBoxes dynamically?

Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
-(void)Check
{
    CGPoint origin = note.frame.origin;
    NSString* head = [note.text substringToIndex:note.selectedRange.location];
    CGSize initialSize = [head sizeWithFont:note.font constrainedToSize:note.contentSize];
    NSUInteger startOfLine = [head length];

    NSString* tail = [head substringFromIndex:startOfLine];
    CGSize lineSize = [tail sizeWithFont:note.font forWidth:note.contentSize.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGPoint cursor = origin;
    cursor.x += lineSize.width+15;
    cursor.y += initialSize.height - lineSize.height-130;

checkbox = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cursor.x,cursor.y,15,15)];
    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk.png"]forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk.png"]forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    checkbox.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=YES;
    [checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(ChkUnChk) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [note addSubview:checkbox];
}

-(void)ChkUnChk
{
    if(checkUnCheck==NO)
    {
        [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checkUnCheck=YES;
    }
    else if(checkUnCheck==YES)
    {
        [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checkUnCheck=NO;
    }
}

-(void)checkboxSelected:(id)sender
{
    checkBoxSelected = !checkBoxSelected;
    [checkbox setSelected:checkBoxSelected];
}
```

here note --> `UITextView`,checkbox --> `UIButton`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a `NSMutableArray`..

**in .h file**

```
NSMutableArray *selectedBtnarr;
```

**in .m file**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
         selectedBtnarr=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   }
```

Then, you have to set tag property of UIButton. Each Button has different tag.

```
-(void)ChkUnChk:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *Str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",btn.tag];
    BOOL flag=   [selectedBtnarr containsObject:Str];

    if (flag==YES)
    {
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [selectedBtnarr removeObject:Str];
    }
    else
    {
        [selectedBtnarr addObject:Str];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much. Its working good. how can i delete these checkBoxes   using backspace or delete key

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the tag of the buttons going to be created with any integer(Use looping). And then call the selector with the `-(void)ChkUnChk:(id)sender{}`. Thus the method will be called for the tagged button only.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the sample source code

https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSCheckBoxView

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write down below 2 methods. As you're already allocating button's different methods for different states, you'll need to change those states only and execute code as per button's state.

```
-(void)Check
{
    CGPoint origin = note.frame.origin;
    NSString* head = [note.text substringToIndex:note.selectedRange.location];
    CGSize initialSize = [head sizeWithFont:note.font constrainedToSize:note.contentSize];
    NSUInteger startOfLine = [head length];

    NSString* tail = [head substringFromIndex:startOfLine];
    CGSize lineSize = [tail sizeWithFont:note.font forWidth:note.contentSize.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGPoint cursor = origin;
    cursor.x += lineSize.width+15;
    cursor.y += initialSize.height - lineSize.height-130;

    checkbox = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cursor.x,cursor.y,15,15)];
    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk.png"]forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk.png"]forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    checkbox.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=YES;
    [checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(ChkUnChk) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [note addSubview:checkbox];
}

-(void)ChkUnChk:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = sender;
    if(btn.selected==NO)
    {
        [btn setSelected:YES];
    }
    else if(btn.selected==YES)
    {
        [btn setSelected:NO];
    }
}
```

Let me know if you stuck at somewhere.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your response.. i have got this error when i enter the code inside chkUnChk Method             Property 'selected' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Comment: thank u so much... now how can delete these checkboxes if me created more... by backspace or delete key

Comment: for that you'll need to manage this checkboxes by tags. And manage one  -(void)Mth_Delete:(id)sender and delete that checkbox as per tag same as we have done in ChkUnchk method.